# Electron devtools "ignored scripts" between restarts

Tags: javascript, electron, google-chrome-devtools, devtools

I depend a lot on having a list of "ignored scripts" in my devtools, but in Electron the list is lost after a restart.

Is there a way to either persist settings between restarts or to programmatically add the ignored scripts during my app start.